# Out of memory Memory leak issue

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Hi everyone I am developing an application which uses many images and activities.Its an digital magazine providing application.In my application one situation comes which I should show all the magazine to users using thumbnails using the Viewgroup of image and textview dynamically.My application is almost complete.But am really struggling with the memory issues.

In my application many memory leaks are coming.I managed in many places where I can locate using System.gc(); .recycle(); hashmap and all other possible ways.But still my application has same problem.

I want to locate where this memory leak happens in my code.I used DDMS allocation tracker,MAT and Heap still am only getting an rough idea.I want to locate it in my code to manage it.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.I am stuck here and I have no ways ahead.:(

Comment: MAT should be the right tool. How do you know there are memory leaks ?